# Merging multiindex dataframe with itself based on a dictionary value mappings

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multiindex dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({('group', ''): {0: 'A',
  1: 'A',
  2: 'A',
  3: 'A',
  4: 'A',
  5: 'A',
  6: 'A',
  7: 'A',
  8: 'B',
  9: 'B',
  10: 'B',
  11: 'B',
  12: 'B',
  13: 'B',
  14: 'B',
  15: 'B'},
 ('category', ''): {0: 'Amazon',
  1: 'Netflix',
  2: 'Apple',
  3: 'Facebook',
  4: 'Tesla',
  5: 'Uber',
  6: 'Google',
  7: 'total',
  8: 'Amazon',
  9: 'Netflix',
  10: 'Apple',
  11: 'Facebook',
  12: 'Tesla',
  13: 'Uber',
  14: 'Google',
  15: 'total'},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 195.0,
  1: 37.0,
  2: 61.0,
  3: 106.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 4.0,
  6: 61.0,
  7: 477.0,
  8: 50.0,
  9: 17.0,
  10: 50.0,
  11: 75.0,
  12: 14.0,
  13: 3.0,
  14: 43.0,
  15: 252.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-06-29 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 1268.85,
  1: 15323.800000000001,
  2: 18274.385000000002,
  3: 19722.65,
  4: 1688.6749999999997,
  5: 1906.0,
  6: 55547.255,
  7: 113731.615,
  8: 3219.6499999999996,
  9: 5918.5,
  10: 15852.060000000001,
  11: 17743.7,
  12: 1708.75,
  13: 937.01,
  14: 37795.15,
  15: 83174.82},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 96.0,
  1: 34.0,
  2: 56.0,
  3: 106.0,
  4: 13.0,
  5: 9.0,
  6: 44.0,
  7: 358.0,
  8: 101.0,
  9: 13.0,
  10: 22.0,
  11: 120.0,
  12: 8.0,
  13: 1.0,
  14: 40.0,
  15: 305.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-06-28 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 5194.95,
  1: 11461.25,
  2: 19102.219999999994,
  3: 22796.420000000002,
  4: 992.6,
  5: 3671.15,
  6: 30853.115,
  7: 94071.705,
  8: 6022.299999999998,
  9: 4749.000000000001,
  10: 7373.6,
  11: 33514.0,
  12: 902.01,
  13: 349.3,
  14: 35943.45,
  15: 88853.66},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 26.0,
  1: 10.0,
  2: 39.0,
  3: 79.0,
  4: 10.0,
  5: 5.0,
  6: 49.0,
  7: 218.0,
  8: 89.0,
  9: 21.0,
  10: 34.0,
  11: 133.0,
  12: 20.0,
  13: 3.0,
  14: 66.0,
  15: 366.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2020-07-06 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 3978.15,
  1: 4280.15,
  2: 12138.96,
  3: 19084.175,
  4: 1495.1,
  5: 1764.15,
  6: 40033.46000000001,
  7: 82774.145,
  8: 8314.92,
  9: 6962.844999999999,
  10: 12776.649999999996,
  11: 28048.075,
  12: 3053.2000000000003,
  13: 1264.655,
  14: 55104.21000000002,
  15: 115524.55500000001},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'total_orders'): {0: 45.0,
  1: 13.0,
  2: 47.0,
  3: 87.0,
  4: 8.0,
  5: 2.0,
  6: 45.0,
  7: 247.0,
  8: 81.0,
  9: 9.0,
  10: 36.0,
  11: 143.0,
  12: 9.0,
  13: 1.0,
  14: 56.0,
  15: 335.0},
 (pd.Timestamp('2021-07-07 00:00:00'), 'total_sales'): {0: 7556.414999999998,
  1: 4024.97,
  2: 14985.05,
  3: 16790.899999999998,
  4: 1034.45,
  5: 1385.65,
  6: 36202.729999999996,
  7: 81980.16499999998,
  8: 5600.544999999999,
  9: 3885.1499999999996,
  10: 11209.92,
  11: 32832.61,
  12: 1191.5,
  13: 599.0,
  14: 42137.44500000001,
  15: 97456.17000000001}}).set_index(['group','category'])
```

I am trying to add `last_year_sales` next to `total_sales`. For example, in the `df` we have `2020-06-29` and `2021-06-28` which both are the first weeks of July.

In reality, the weeks are ordered from `2018` to `2021`.

I am interested in dates from the first week of July to the current date. So the problem is that I am not sure how I should merge the dataframe with itself renaming the last years week sales to `last_year_sales` and merging it to the right place, which is the same week, just a different year. I though of using this dictionary that notes `2020` and `2021` corresponding weeks:

```
date_maps = {'2020-06-29' : '2021-06-28',
'2020-07-06' : '2021-07-05',
'2020-07-13' : '2021-07-12',
'2020-07-20' : '2021-07-19',
'2020-07-27' : '2021-07-26',
'2020-08-03' : '2021-08-02',
'2020-08-10' : '2021-08-09',
'2020-08-17' : '2021-08-16',
'2020-08-24' : '2021-08-23',
'2020-08-31' : '2021-08-30',
'2020-09-07' : '2021-09-06',
'2020-09-14' : '2021-09-13',
'2020-09-21' : '2021-09-20',
'2020-09-28' : '2021-09-27',
'2020-10-05' : '2021-10-04',
'2020-10-12' : '2021-10-11',
'2020-10-19' : '2021-10-18',
'2020-10-26' : '2021-10-25',
'2020-11-02' : '2021-11-01',
'2020-11-09' : '2021-11-08',
'2020-11-16' : '2021-11-15',
'2020-11-23' : '2021-11-22',
'2020-11-30' : '2021-11-29',
'2020-12-07' : '2021-12-06',
'2020-12-14' : '2021-12-13',
'2020-12-21' : '2021-12-20',
'2020-12-28' : '2021-12-27',
'2021-01-04' : '2022-01-03',
'2021-01-11' : '2022-01-10',
'2021-01-18' : '2022-01-17',
'2021-01-25' : '2022-01-24',
'2021-02-01' : '2022-01-31',
'2021-02-08' : '2022-02-07',
'2021-02-15' : '2022-02-14',
'2021-02-22' : '2022-02-21',
'2021-03-01' : '2022-02-28',
'2021-03-08' : '2022-03-07',
'2021-03-15' : '2022-03-14',
'2021-03-22' : '2022-03-21',
'2021-03-29' : '2022-03-28',
'2021-04-05' : '2022-04-04',
'2021-04-12' : '2022-04-11',
'2021-04-19' : '2022-04-18',
'2021-04-26' : '2022-04-25',
'2021-05-03' : '2022-05-02',
'2021-05-10' : '2022-05-09',
'2021-05-17' : '2022-05-16',
'2021-05-24' : '2022-05-23',
'2021-05-31' : '2022-05-30',
'2021-06-07' : '2022-06-06',
'2021-06-14' : '2022-06-13',
'2021-06-21' : '2022-06-20',
'2021-06-28' : '2022-06-27'}
```

My desired output would look like this:

```
                        2021-06-28                                                                         2021-07-07      
                        total_orders    total_sales     last_year_sales     last_year_total_orders         total_orders     total_sales     last_year_sales     last_year_total_orders
group       category                                
A           Amazon      195.000         1,268.850       5,194.950           195.000                         ...            ...              ...                 ...
            Netflix     37.000          15,323.800      11,461.250          20.00
            Apple       61.000          18,274.385      19,102.220          30.00   
            Facebook    106.000         19,722.650      22,796.420          50.00
            Tesla       13.000          1,688.675       992.600             25.00
            Uber        4.000           1,906.000       3,671.150           15.00
            Google      61.000          55,547.255      30,853.115          10.00
            total       477.000         113,731.615     94,071.705          56.00
B           Amazon      50.000          3,219.650       6,022.300           400.00
            Netflix     17.000          5,918.500       4,749.000           30.00
            Apple       50.000          15,852.060      7,373.600           27.00
            Facebook    75.000          17,743.700      33,514.000          15.00
            Tesla       14.000          1,708.750       902.010             66.00
            Uber        3.000           937.010         349.300             94.00
            Google      43.000          37,795.150      35,943.450          65.00
            total       252.000         83,174.820      88,853.660          61.00
```

Where `last_year_x` denotes the `sales` and `orders` from the last year week, which is denoted in the `date_maps` dictionary.
I would provide what I've tried but I do not know where to begin.

Answer (score 0):

you can rename the columns to get what you need, assuming the dates are always in order of `this_year` and then `last_year`

```
# Get the current column names in level 1
l = df.droplevel(0, axis=1).columns
l

Index(['total_orders', 'total_sales', 'total_orders', 'total_sales',
       'total_orders', 'total_sales', 'total_orders', 'total_sales'],
      dtype='object')

# Pair up the column names by this year and last year
temp = list(zip(l[::2],l[1::2]))
temp

[('total_orders', 'total_sales'),
 ('total_orders', 'total_sales'),
 ('total_orders', 'total_sales'),
 ('total_orders', 'total_sales')]

# Do a text replacement on the odd pairs (last years')
pairs = [(x[0].replace('total_','last_years_'), x[1].replace('total_','last_years_')) if i%2 == 1 else x for i, x in enumerate(temp)]
pairs

[('total_orders', 'total_sales'),
 ('last_years_orders', 'last_years_sales'),
 ('total_orders', 'total_sales'),
 ('last_years_orders', 'last_years_sales')]

# Flatten the list
flatten_list = [item for subl in pairs for item in subl]
flatten_list

['total_orders',
 'total_sales',
 'last_years_orders',
 'last_years_sales',
 'total_orders',
 'total_sales',
 'last_years_orders',
 'last_years_sales']

# Get a copy of the dataframe with level 0 dropped
dfdrop = df.droplevel(0, axis=1)

# Change the column names to the flattened list
# Note this could also be achieved with df.rename...
dfdrop.columns = flatten_list
dfdrop

    total_orders    total_sales last_years_orders   last_years_sales    total_orders    total_sales last_years_orders   last_years_sales
group   category                                
A   Amazon  195.0   1268.850    96.0    5194.950    26.0    3978.150    45.0    7556.415
Netflix 37.0    15323.800   34.0    11461.250   10.0    4280.150    13.0    4024.970
Apple   61.0    18274.385   56.0    19102.220   39.0    12138.960   47.0    14985.050
Facebook    106.0   19722.650   106.0   22796.420   79.0    19084.175   87.0    16790.900
Tesla   13.0    1688.675    13.0    992.600 10.0    1495.100    8.0 1034.450
Uber    4.0 1906.000    9.0 3671.150    5.0 1764.150    2.0 1385.650
Google  61.0    55547.255   44.0    30853.115   49.0    40033.460   45.0    36202.730
total   477.0   113731.615  358.0   94071.705   218.0   82774.145   247.0   81980.165
B   Amazon  50.0    3219.650    101.0   6022.300    89.0    8314.920    81.0    5600.545
Netflix 17.0    5918.500    13.0    4749.000    21.0    6962.845    9.0 3885.150
Apple   50.0    15852.060   22.0    7373.600    34.0    12776.650   36.0    11209.920
Facebook    75.0    17743.700   120.0   33514.000   133.0   28048.075   143.0   32832.610
Tesla   14.0    1708.750    8.0 902.010 20.0    3053.200    9.0 1191.500
Uber    3.0 937.010 1.0 349.300 3.0 1264.655    1.0 599.000
Google  43.0    37795.150   40.0    35943.450   66.0    55104.210   56.0    42137.445
total   252.0   83174.820   305.0   88853.660   366.0   115524.555  335.0   97456.170

# Get a list of the datetimes
dt = pd.DataFrame(df.T.index.get_level_values(0), columns=["Date"])
dt["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(dt["Date"])
dt

Date
0   2020-06-29
1   2020-06-29
2   2021-06-28
3   2021-06-28
4   2020-07-06
5   2020-07-06
6   2021-07-07
7   2021-07-07

# Make a multiindex and add back into dfdrop
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dfdrop.columns.tolist(), dt["Date"]])
dfdrop.columns = idx
dfdrop


        total_orders    total_sales last_years_orders   last_years_sales    total_orders    total_sales last_years_orders   last_years_sales
Date    2020-06-29  2020-06-29  2021-06-28  2021-06-28  2020-07-06  2020-07-06  2021-07-07  2021-07-07
group   category                                
A   Amazon  195.0   1268.850    96.0    5194.950    26.0    3978.150    45.0    7556.415
Netflix 37.0    15323.800   34.0    11461.250   10.0    4280.150    13.0    4024.970
Apple   61.0    18274.385   56.0    19102.220   39.0    12138.960   47.0    14985.050
Facebook    106.0   19722.650   106.0   22796.420   79.0    19084.175   87.0    16790.900
Tesla   13.0    1688.675    13.0    992.600 10.0    1495.100    8.0 1034.450
Uber    4.0 1906.000    9.0 3671.150    5.0 1764.150    2.0 1385.650
Google  61.0    55547.255   44.0    30853.115   49.0    40033.460   45.0    36202.730
total   477.0   113731.615  358.0   94071.705   218.0   82774.145   247.0   81980.165
B   Amazon  50.0    3219.650    101.0   6022.300    89.0    8314.920    81.0    5600.545
Netflix 17.0    5918.500    13.0    4749.000    21.0    6962.845    9.0 3885.150
Apple   50.0    15852.060   22.0    7373.600    34.0    12776.650   36.0    11209.920
Facebook    75.0    17743.700   120.0   33514.000   133.0   28048.075   143.0   32832.610
Tesla   14.0    1708.750    8.0 902.010 20.0    3053.200    9.0 1191.500
Uber    3.0 937.010 1.0 349.300 3.0 1264.655    1.0 599.000
Google  43.0    37795.150   40.0    35943.450   66.0    55104.210   56.0    42137.445
total   252.0   83174.820   305.0   88853.660   366.0   115524.555  335.0   97456.170
```

This gets close to what you want but it preserves all of the dates.

Comment: The dates go in order from `2018` to the present as I've mentioned in my question. Does this work with ordered column names?

Comment: Ah, no from your dataframe it looked like the dates were ordered by month/day: `2020-06-29 00:00:00 2021-06-28 00:00:00 2020-07-06 00:00:00 2021-07-07 00:00:00`. It works as long as this is true. Also I've noticed I've dropped the date from the column names so will add that back in.

Comment: I've added the dates back in as a multiindex.

Comment: I see, but the problem is that the data structure is different and I can't work with that.

Comment: If you sort your columns by week number or by month/day then the the above should work. You can use something like this: `dt["week"] = dt["Date"].dt.isocalendar().week
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([dt["Date"], dt["week"], df.T.index.get_level_values(1)])
df2 = df
df2.columns = idx
df2.sort_values(by="week", axis=1)` assuming you have `dt` declared as per the code in the answer.